# Can I replace the system settings with the old one?

Tags: 11.10, settings

I recently upgraded my Google Cr-48 to Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu 11.04. Is there any way I can replace the new system settings with one that is actually useful, like the old one?

Comment: What are you trying to do? most things are available from the System Settings menu - you can always use the Dash to find anything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

There are many tweaks and solutions to edit things around that are not the same as in 11.04 were but you wont be able to use your previous version system settings panels.

Comment: To further explain, this is because of the transition from GNOME 2 to GNOME 3 when upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10. The old system settings are simply no longer compatible with the underlying system.

Comment: @WarriorIng64. that may be true for some applications but a lot are still there or can be installed without them appearing in the *System settings* window (e.g. ccsm, remote desktop, system monitor to name only a few). This is different ot previous releases.

Comment: @Takkat thats not the same as the question asks. we have to agree with Warriorlng64 on this.

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question. It can be lived with it is just very annoying.

Comment: Fully agree, many things have changed with the new 11.10, its just a mater of time before all the comments start to be implemented as functionality since some of the stuff missing are really needed ;)